# Would ZF result from this Zermelo \ von Neumann ordinal race?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Define: $Z(x)\iff trs(x) \land \forall y \in x \, (\exists k (y= \{k\})  \lor (y \subset x \land trs(y) \land \forall z \in y \, (\{z\} \in y))$

Where: $trs(y) \iff \forall a \, \forall b \, (a \in b \in y \to a \in y)$

In words: a Zermelo set is a transitive set of singletons or transitive subsets of it that are closed under singletons.

I'm assuming "Foundation scheme" here.

Now we define a *Zermelo ordinal* as an element of a Zermelo set.

What I call as Zermelo \von Neumann ordinal race is the following principle:

If an initial class $I$ of Zermelo ordinals is bounded in cardinality by a class of von Neumann ordinals that can be placed in one-to-one relation with a subclass of $I$, then there is a Zermelo ordinal bigger than all of those Zermelo ordinals, and also a von Neumann ordinal bigger than all of those placed von Neumanns.

Where: "*class bounded in cardinality by a class*" means that every element of the former class is smaller or equal in cardinality to an element of the latter class. An *initial* class, is a class closed under predecessor relation.

Now if we add this principle to $\sf Z - Infinity + \forall x \exists \alpha: x \in V_\alpha$, would that get us to $\sf ZF$?

Comment: If I understand the principle correctly, it's inconsistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ (and indeed much less): take the class of all Zermelo ordinals and compare it with the class of all von Neumann ordinals.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, your comment gives me the impression that you think Zermelo ordinals are less than von Neumann ordinals? What's the proof of that?